# Zip array of HTTP calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

[In this link](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/angular-how-to-use-rxjss-zip-operator-to-make-http-requests) it explains how to make two HTTP calls grouped by a zip as below:

```
const groupedResponse = zip(this.getTeachers(), this.getStudents());
```

But what I have is an array of HTTP calls, for example:

```
 getHttp(obj) {
     return this.http.get ...
 }


 var array = [];
 array.push(this.getHttp(obj1));
 array.push(this.getHttp(obj2));
```

I tried to zip the array but it doesn't work, probably because it's not a list of comma separated values:

```
const groupedResponse = zip(array).
        subscribe((response: any[]) => {
            for (var i=0; i < response.length; i++)
                console.log(response[i].res);
        });
```

How to zip the array of HTTP calls?

Comment: To unpack the list, use `zip(...array)` instead

Comment: I think it's better to use `forkJoin` for multiple http request as it does all you need (execute multiple http requests at the same time - wait for all to complete before emitting the results as an array) and nothing more. `zip`'s unique feature is to emit an array of values whenever all sources have emitted since their last emit. `forkJoin` only ever emits once, `zip` can generally emit multiple times. You don't need `zip`'s unique feature but if you use `zip` someone reading your code could think that you do. `forkJoin` also accepts an array directly `forkJoin(array)` (no need to spread it).

Comment: Yes forkJoin may be best. Make sure to use an array of values for parameters.